# Azure DevOps Build Task: create a zip with contents identical to Visual Studio Publish

Tags: visual-studio, azure-pipelines-build-task

In Visual Studio, when we publish to a folder, that folder contains exactly what we need to deploy.

In Azure Pipeline, the Build Solution task produces a a bunch of (to us) unnecessary files plus a zip file (nice!).  The zip contains the files we need, but buried in an crazy deep folder path:

```
\Content\D_C\a\1\s\src\MyProject\obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp\our-files.dll
```

What we would prefer is:

```
\our-files.dll
```

It also modifies connectionStrings in the web.config to support the deploy script it ships with.  We don't need that script and that modification is a pain (which we disabled by adding`<AutoParameterizationWebConfigConnectionStrings>false</...>` to the .csproj file - yuck!)` .

We tried fussing with the parameters in the Build Solution step:

```
/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:PackageLocation="$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)\\"
```

- Changing `DeployOnBuild` to `false` caused the $(build.artifactsstagingdirectory) to be empty (causing the next step to deploy nothing)
- Changing `WebPublishMethod` to `FileSystem` made no difference (try finding documentation on the allowed values!)
- Changing `PackageAsSingleFile` to `false` did what one would expect - no zip, but the contents were still buried in that deep folder structure.

Our downstream script *could* open the manifest file, xpath out the deep path baked into the zip (does the path always start with `d_C`?), unzip and grab the contents from there - but what a pain and how unnecessary.

Is there a way to publish just a nice clean build - a zip with contents that directly unpacks to the same files as a plain-jane Publish from Visual Studio does?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In the Visual Studio Build step change "MSBuild Arguments" to

```
/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:PackageLocation="$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)\\"    /p:UseWPP_CopyWebApplication=true  /p:OutDir="$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)"
```

The key thing is /p:OutDir="$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)" resolves the directory issue and /p:UseWPP_CopyWebApplication=true removes web.config.release and web.config.debug

Then update Publish Build Artifacts step "Path to publish" to

```
$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)\_PublishedWebsites
```

Comment: Thank you - minor tweaking and this is now doing the trick.  It doesn't zip though (not a requirement - just a nice to have).  Have you figured out how to do that?

Comment: Np you could put in a zip step to solve the nice to have.

Comment: I can't seem get that to work, my step is failing on the publish artifact with error "##[error]Publishing build artifacts failed with an error: Not found PathtoPublish: D:\a\1\a\_PublishedWebsites" Does "_PublishedWebsites" need to be specified in the build step ?

Comment: awesome, glad I found this.  I have been beating my head all day on this.  microsoft needs to include some of this info in the docs for this task since this seems to be a VERY common problem that many are trying to get past.